# Mysql database / PHP + LARAVEL: how to get some information from database time by time?

Tags: php, laravel

i have a question, how can i get information from database time by time? For exmaple: i have 1000 users, after 0.05 seconds when someone opens route where this users showed, i want to load first 98 users, then after 0.05 another 98 and etcecular, i want them to grow from 0 to 1000 in 3 second and show result like : TOTAL USERS(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 "TIME BY TIME, for every 0.01 three users or etc" ? in laravel php. I want when someone will refresh page where this total users store, the calculation of total users reset and go again.
Thank you.

Comment: Why would you want this, it seems horrible for performance.

Comment: i just have information with A:1000 B:1000 C:1000 and on home page it shows total 3000, i just want it not to go like 3000 , go by time for idk for what its just pretty

Comment: Your question, and this follow up are really unclear. Specify (clearly!) what you want and what you've tried. [SO | How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, why would you choose prettiness over absolute horrific performance. And what would even be the use case of showing all users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, i need animation for this.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).